# tagging credit after gathering accumulation of equations

Tags: equations

need help
I need to put these three equations in three lines covered by a big parenthesis on the right side with the tag (Tolman 1939)

```
$$KP=e^{-\lambda} \Big( \frac {\nu'}{r}+ \frac {1}{r^2}\Big)-\frac {1}{r^2}$$

$$ KP= e^{-\lambda} \Big(\frac {\nu ''}{2}-\frac {\lambda ' \nu '}{4} + \frac {(\nu')^2}{4} + \frac {\nu' -\lambda'}{2r}\Big)$$

 $$K \rho c^2= e^{-\lambda}\Big (\frac {\lambda '}{r}-\frac {1}{r^2}\Big) +\frac {1}{r^2}$$
```

Comment: Comment aside: you should not use `$$ … $$`, which is plain TeX and can result in wrong vertical spacing. Use `\[ … \]` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a brace on just one side with a `\left.` on one side and an `\right\}` to add the brace on the right.

[image]

### References:

- [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
             KP &= e^{-\lambda} \Big( \frac {\nu'}{r}+ \frac {1}{r^2}\Big)-\frac {1}{r^2} \\
             KP &= e^{-\lambda} \Big(\frac {\nu ''}{2}-\frac {\lambda ' \nu '}{4} + \frac {(\nu')^2}{4} + \frac {\nu' -\lambda'}{2r}\Big) \\
     K \rho c^2 &= e^{-\lambda}\Big (\frac {\lambda '}{r}-\frac {1}{r^2}\Big) +\frac {1}{r^2}
\end{aligned}
\right\} \tag{Tolman 1939}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A variant with a slighly simpler code, thanks to the `empheq` package (that loads `mathtools`, from the same author, and `amsmath`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}[right = \empheqrbrace]
             KP &= e^{-\lambda} \Big( \frac {\nu'}{r}+ \frac {1}{r^2}\Big)-\frac {1}{r^2}  \\
             KP &= e^{-\lambda} \Big(\frac {\nu ''}{2}-\frac {\lambda ' \nu '}{4} + \frac {(\nu')^2}{4} + \frac {\nu' -\lambda'}{2r}\Big)  \tag{Tolman 1939}\\
     K \rho c^2 &= e^{-\lambda}\Big (\frac {\lambda '}{r}-\frac {1}{r^2}\Big) +\frac {1}{r^2}
%
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]